# take data from one table and put it into another along with new information

Tags: php, mysql, database, webforms

I have 2 tables. the first is customers the second is invoice, both have a row for "customer ID". When adding a new invoice through a web form how do I make it so it will take the "customer ID" from customers and put it into the "customer ID" in invoice along with the new information upon submission of the form?

This is the code from my index.php

```
?php
include 'DBConfig.php';
//Insert or Update contact information
if(isset($_POST['action_type']))
{
if ($_POST['action_type'] == 'add' or $_POST['action_type'] == 'edit')
{
    //Sanitize the data and assign to variables
    $invum = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['invnum']));
    $cost = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['cost']));

    if ($_POST['action_type'] == 'add')
    {
        $sql = "insert into invoice set 
                cost = '$cost'";
    }else{
        $sql = "update invoice set 
                cost = '$cost',
                where invnum = $invnum";
    }


    if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql))
    {
        echo 'Error Saving Data. ' . mysqli_error($link);
        exit(); 
    }
}
header('Location: invoicelist.php');
exit();
}
//End Insert or Update contact information

//Start of edit contact read
$gresult = ''; //declare global variable
if(isset($_POST["action"]) and $_POST["action"]=="edit"){
$id = (isset($_POST["ci"])? $_POST["ci"] : '');
$sql = "select invnum, cost from invoice 
        where invnum = $id";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if(!$result)
{
    echo mysqli_error($link);
    exit();
}

$gresult = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

include 'invoiceupdate.php';
exit();
}
//end of edit contact read
```

Comment: You have the data in `$gresult`. Just insert them accordingly with new data.

Comment: @sgtBOSE   I'm afraid I'm not following you.  I am pretty new to PHP and MySql.  I have updated my original question to show my entire index.php

Comment: Try to limit your examples minimal, verifiable and complete : [see more here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here, your index is quite big - limit it to your problem alone :-)